# Close World Assumption in Protégé

Tags: owl, protege

Is it possible to force reasoning over an OWL ontology basing on a close world assumption (CWA) in Protégé? Obviously OWL bases on OWA, but I need to close it.

Comment: I edited your question to remove the resource request, since "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: Depending on your use case, you can get forms of closed world reasoning in OWL.  It just requires some extra axioms to do the closing.  But you haven't shown any of your data, so we can't really offer any help with that yet.  What problem are you actually running into?

Comment: Please read my comment under your reply below

Comment: under what reply? Those two comments are the only things I've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reason using close world assumption without changing your ontology you need a reasoner that supports that feature. Pellet has an option to use closed world assumption, you will have to check Protégé's settings to make sure it is configurable though.

I'm not aware of other reasoners providing it.

If you cannot use Pellet, you'll have to follow Joshua's suggestion in the comments: modify the ontology to close the world with the right assertions. We can't recommend anything to do that without seeing the ontology, though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am doing something incorrectly or Pellet does not work as I would like it to. I am trying to check the correctnes of the following expression by asserting specific individuals:
                                                                  
EquivalentClasses( :A 
   ObjectUnionOf(
      ObjectExactCardinality( 1 :ccc :B )
      ObjectIntersectionOf(   
          ObjectMinCardinality( 3 :ccc :B ) 
          ObjectMaxCardinality( 6 :ccc :B ) ) ) )