# How to configure Protégé to perform Closed World Reasoning?

Tags: owl, protege, reasoning, pellet

I want to validate instances against the minimum cardinality restrictions of my ontology. To do so, I have to perform Closed World Reasoning.

According to several posts, Protégé supports such reasoning with Pellet reasoner. However, I could not find any tutorial about how to do it.

My question is how to configure Protégé (or Pellet in Protégé) to perform Closed world reasoning?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: there is no such option, I don't where you read this. Epistemic operator is no option in Protege, you could check Pellet via OWL API. Other options are to use rule based reasoning, SHACL, Pellet ICV, SPARQL ,etc ..

Comment: I read this in the answer to this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762628/close-world-assumption-in-prot%C3%A9g%C3%A9 and another one here http://protege-project.136.n4.nabble.com/local-closed-world-reasoning-K-operator-via-Pellet-td4671042.html. It seems that it is possible..

Comment: and both links say that it's not possible in Protege as I was saying too, or not? Pellet might have some extended options, but you have to use Pellet via OWL API or if you don't mind CLI. Sure, you could also modify the Pellet plugin for Protege if you have time and are able to do so, the source code is online: https://github.com/stardog-union/pellet/tree/master/protege - still, I doubt there is a simple flag. And just for reference: https://github.com/stardog-union/pellet/wiki/FAQ#does-pellet-support-closed-world-reasoning

Comment: as well as the available options: https://github.com/stardog-union/pellet/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/mindswap/pellet/PelletOptions.java